# Async function deadlocks in WebMethod, but works fine if called in Page_Load

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webforms, webmethod

I have a WebForms project that is trying to make use of some `async` code. During early development, I was simply calling my `async` code in `Page_Load` (which is also `async`) and writing the result to the `Response`. Nice and easy for testing. It all worked as expected.

The code can be summed up as:

1. Get the Azure authorization token.
2. Make an HTTP request towards Azure's REST API.
3. Return results to client.

I was quite surprised, therefore, when I tried to call this `async` method inside a `WebMethod` and it failed. It seems to be deadlocking on other `async` code (specifically the Azure AD [`AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt459169.aspx) method).

My first thought was some context sorcery, but `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't have any effect. So I'm quite at a loss as to what is different. I've tried with the `WebMethod` being `async` or not with no difference in results. Quick testing reveals that there's nothing wrong with how this `WebMethod` is configured -- having my code return early (before reaching the call to the AD code) has it work as expected. Although there's nothing asynchronous happening then.

I also tried using the non-asynchronous method for getting the Azure AD token. This works fine, but then my application gets stuck when it tries to make the HTTP request (using the RestSharp.Portable library, which only offers `async` methods). My code there looks like:

```
protected async Task<JObject> PerformRequest(string path, Method method, string apiVersion, string requestBody)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://management.azure.com");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(path, method);
    request.AddParameter("api-version", apiVersion);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", await this.GetAccessTokenAsync());
    IRestResponse<JObject> response = await client.Execute<JObject>(request);
    return response.Data;
}
```

The code that my working `Page_Load` and non-working `WebMethod` used was virtually identical, except that the `WebMethod` returns the result while `Page_Load` wrote the result to the `Response`.

`GetAccessToken` looks like:

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    string tenantId = "xxx";
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "xxx", clientSecret: "xxx=");
    AuthenticationResult result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);

    if (result == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

    return this.accessToken = result.AccessTokenType + " " + result.AccessToken;
}
```

The call to all of this is made directly in the `WebMethod` (as the only thing the `WebMethod` currently does):

```
return await this.PerformRequest("xxx", Method.GET, "xxx", null).ContinueWith(result => result.ToString());
```

Why might my application be having this problem for calling this code in a `WebMethod`, but not in `Page_Load`? What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Can we see where you call `PerformRequest`? Do you wait on the result of the call to `PerformRequest` anywhere?

Comment: Can you post the code to this.GetAccessToken?

Comment: Also, please could you post the results of running this code with an HTTP sniffer, like fiddler.

Comment: @Aron, I've added code for `GetAccessToken`. It's pretty much the same as the MDSN demonstrates.

Comment: @spender, I've added this to the question.

Comment: @Aron, without changing anything, we get stuck in `GetAccessToken`, so naturally no HTTP request is made. Although the HTTP request is never made if we use the synchronous approach in `GetAccessToken` (ie, when we're getting stuck in the HTTP call.

Comment: Hi Mike. I would be very interested in a fiddler dump. I suspect you are hitting some network port limits in Windows client edition.

Comment: @Aron, I'm not sure what exactly you're asking for. I'm not familiar with Fiddler being able to identify if a request is attempted but never goes through. Although I can't see why that would be the case. IIRC, Win 8.1 has a 10 connection limit and there should only be 2 going on in this case. Also, this shouldn't be any different from when my application used `Page_Load`, from a networking perspective (except now I am making this request with JS asynchronously instead of as part of the "main" request).

Comment: @Mike Yeah. That was basically what I was on about, except IIS also has limits (I think 3 connections). Anywho, I suggest you put the whole project on a github post the link here and on microsoft...really sounds like a real bug to me.

Comment: @Aron, 3 is the basic edition. The enterprise edition (which I'm using) has a connection limit of 10. Sadly, I'm not able to put it on GitHub since this is a closed source, work related project, so can only post snippets.

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
IRestResponse<JObject> response = await client.Execute<JObject>(request);
```

to

```
IRestResponse<JObject> response = await client.Execute<JObject>(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

does this help you?
problem is that the both "await" are waiting to capture the same context at the same time, ConfigureWait prevent this (read its doc)

Comment: Sounds like you are suggesting that the two inner Tasks are run concurrently. But I think it should run in sequence, there should be no "at the same time" happening.

Comment: be aware, async/await pattern is a pitfall http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Yes. But it is the interaction with Task.Result that caused issues. The OP is running "async all the way down".

Comment: No, this doesn't make a difference. I don't see why it would, since these two awaits are supposed to be sequential (the Authentication header must be set before the request can be made). At any rate, trying to causes no change. It also doesn't seem to explain why this would work "normally", but not with `WebMethod`.